# get randomly only one record Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

i'm totally noob in Laravel and don't know structure and syntax of language but deadline if very soon and I don't have a time to start from scratch so I need help.

I want to display records from table randomly but from only one table must to be only one record (nested query)

is there any solution for it ?

this is my code from controller:

```
$alldepartments = Department::translatedIn(app()->getLocale())
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->first()
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->get();
```

and this is blade:

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; white-space: nowrap">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap">
                        @foreach($alldepartments as $mydepartment)
                            @foreach($mydepartment->employees as $employee)
                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                                    <a href="{{ url('employee/'. $employee->id) }}">
                                        <div class="single_advisor_profile wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.2s; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
                                            <div class="advisor_thumb">
                                                <img src="{{ asset('uploads/employees/'.$employee->image) }}" alt="" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="single_advisor_details_info">
                                                <h6>{{$employee->name}}</h6>
                                                <p class="designation">{{$mydepartment->name}}</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
```

it is working for randomly getting records but it gives me all record from each table but I need to take only one!!

Comment: Switch `->first()` and `->inRandomOrder()`

Comment: same result, its give me all records

Comment: @Danny That's because of the `get()`. Remove it.

Comment: without get I get an error Attempt to read property "---" on array

Comment: I don't see any line of code in your sample that would cause that. You need to do some debugging effort here; first see if you can get the query working; dump out the value it returns. *Then* make adjustments to your Blade template.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to remove the `first()` method and add a `take(1)` before the `get()` method. The `take()` method is used to get a specific amount of elements.

Comment: That's what the `first()` function does already. The only difference here is your approach will return a single-item collection, whereas `first()` returns the item itself. See the source code: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d3e3667cb6a1513a702713170e7d05cc649202ed/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php#L331; the `first()` function in Eloquent does `return $this->take(1)->get($columns)->first();`. If this solved OP's issue, their issue is the collection-versus-item distinction.